# how to add a sub access route on the access file

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, zend-framework2

I am using a framework (zend 2) for my site; it redirects all URL requests to the index page using ht.access. This works perfectly normally.

However, i know want to add a Wordpress blog to the site.

i dont want the blog subject to the Zend Module and therefore needs to sit independent within the site. this means it cannot be subject to the ht access rules.

Accordignly, Iwant all url that have a directory of Blog

> i.e www.sampleSite/blog

to not be subject to any ht access rule.

Below are my HT access rules. u will note that all URL requests are redirected to the index page.

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

how do i now exclude the Blog directory from these rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution to this is rather simple.

the public folder is accessible within the framework. Accordinly, all i really need to do is to place my wordpress blog folder within it and we are good to go

i.e

```
www.sampleSite/blog
```